# XSLT: XML to JSON - If key/s repeated in data, Merge the Key/s data into one Key concatenate with ";"- "KEY1": "Rate1: - 2000; Rate2: - 3000"

Tags: xslt

XSLT : Merge "LineTransaction" Key column if more than one !!

Please refer below XML and JSON and share the correct XSLT Code

Source XML Data :

```
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:InvoiceRefID>INVOICE-9999</wd:InvoiceRefID>
    <wd:InvoiceNumber>999-1234</wd:InvoiceNumber>
    <wd:InvoiceLine>
    <wd:InvoiceLineRefID>INVOICE_LINE-9999-1</wd:InvoiceLineRefID>
    <wd:LineTransaction wd:Descriptor="Tax Rate1: - 2000">
    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">83888d0f7bb710017f5517e62ca00001</wd:ID>
    </wd:LineTransaction>
    <wd:LineTransaction wd:Descriptor="Vertex Tax Rate2: - 3000">
    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">83888d0f7bb710017f55174bfa7a0002</wd:ID>
    </wd:LineTransaction>
    </wd:InvoiceLine>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
```

Please refer below XSLT Code,

**XSLT Code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/InvoiceAndInvoiceLine" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>[&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:text> &#xA0;{&#xa; </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except wd:InvoiceLine"/>
        <xsl:text>,&#xa;"invoiceLine": [ &#xa; </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:InvoiceLine"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa; &#xA0; ] &#xa; &#xA0; } </xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="wd:*">
        <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test="@wd:Descriptor"><xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',local-name(),'&quot;:&quot;',@wd:Descriptor,'&quot;')"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',local-name(),'&quot;:&quot;',.,'&quot;')"/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="wd:InvoiceLine">
        <xsl:text> &#xA0; { &#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa; &#xA0; }</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,&#xa; </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>       
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="wd:InvoiceLine/*">
        <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test="@wd:Descriptor">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',local-name(),'&quot;:&quot;',@wd:Descriptor,'&quot;')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',local-name(),'&quot;:&quot;',.,'&quot;')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,&#xa; </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is **JSON Output:**

```
[
 {
 "InvoiceRefID":"INVOICE-9999",
 "InvoiceNumber":"999-1234",
 "invoiceLine": [ 
    { 
      "InvoiceLineRefID":"INVOICE_LINE-9999-1",
      "LineTransaction": "Tax Rate1: - 2000",
      "LineTransaction": "Tax Rate2: - 3000"
    }
  ]
  }
]
```

Here is **Expected JSON Output:** above XSLT code not produced right outout

```
[
     {
     "InvoiceRefID":"INVOICE-9999",
     "InvoiceNumber":"999-1234",
     "invoiceLine": [ 
        { 
          "InvoiceLineRefID":"INVOICE_LINE-9999-1",
          "LineTransaction": "Tax Rate1: - 2000; Tax Rate2: - 3000"
        }
      ]
      }
    ]
```

Please verify above and share right solution.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Your XSLT declares `version="3.0"`. If your processor supports XSLT 3.0 then I would suggest you do:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/InvoiceAndInvoiceLine">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- CONVERT INPUT TO XML FOR JSON -->
    <xsl:variable name="xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- OUTPUT -->
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($xml)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
    <array>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </array>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
    <map>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </map>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wd:InvoiceRefID | wd:InvoiceNumber">
    <string key="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wd:InvoiceLine">
    <array key="invoiceLine">
        <map>
            <string key="InvoiceLineRefID">
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:InvoiceLineRefID"/>
            </string>
            <string key="LineTransaction">
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:LineTransaction/@wd:Descriptor" separator="; "/>
            </string>
        </map>
    </array>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With a well-formed (!) XML input:

**XML**

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/InvoiceAndInvoiceLine">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:InvoiceRefID>INVOICE-9999</wd:InvoiceRefID>
        <wd:InvoiceNumber>999-1234</wd:InvoiceNumber>
        <wd:InvoiceLine>
            <wd:InvoiceLineRefID>INVOICE_LINE-9999-1</wd:InvoiceLineRefID>
            <wd:LineTransaction wd:Descriptor="Tax Rate1: - 2000">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">83888d0f7bb710017f5517e62ca00001</wd:ID>
            </wd:LineTransaction>
            <wd:LineTransaction wd:Descriptor="Vertex Tax Rate2: - 3000">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">83888d0f7bb710017f55174bfa7a0002</wd:ID>
            </wd:LineTransaction>
        </wd:InvoiceLine>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

this will produce:

**Result**

```
[{"InvoiceRefID":"INVOICE-9999","InvoiceNumber":"999-1234","invoiceLine":[{"InvoiceLineRefID":"INVOICE_LINE-9999-1","LineTransaction":"Tax Rate1: - 2000; Vertex Tax Rate2: - 3000"}]}]
```